# Bootstrap date-time-piker set current date in my format

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, date

I am new in JS/JQuery and I need create date-time piker. I use bootstrap date-time-piker.

```
<div class="col-sm-8">
   <label for="dtp_input1" class="col-md-2 control-label">Start:</label>
    <div class="input-group date form_dateStart col-md-5" data-date=""
     data-link-field="dtp_input1" data-link-format="dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss">
     <input class="form-control" size="16" type="text" value="now" readonly>
    <span class="input-group-addon"><span
    class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></span>
    <span class="input-group-addon"><span
    class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
</div>
```

and JS

```
$('.form_dateStart').datetimepicker({
    language: 'ru',
    weekStart: 1,
    todayBtn: 1,
    autoclose: 1,
    todayHighlight: 1,
    startView: 2,
    minView: 2,
    setDate: new Date(),
    forceParse: 0
});
```

It work fine. But I need some option

1. Set default date - current date in format `current dd.mm.yyyy 00:00:00`
2. After selecting a date, the choice of time

Comment: please add more details about the plugin you are using exactly

Comment: Please verify whether my solution meets your requirement

Answer (score 0):

This Might Be Helpful...

```
$('.form_dateStart').datetimepicker({
        language: 'ru',
        weekStart: 1,
        todayBtn: 1,
        autoclose: 1,
        todayHighlight: 1,
        startView: 2,
        minView: 2,
        setDate: new Date(),
        forceParse: 0,
        format:'dd.mm.yyyy h:i:s',
        defaultDate: date
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will solve your issue. Set format with jQuery.

```
    $('.form_dateStart').datetimepicker({
        format: 'DD.MM.YYYY hh:mm:ss',
    });

    var d = new Date();

    var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
    var day = d.getDate();

    var output = (day < 10 ? '0' : '') + day + '.' + (month < 10 ? '0' : '') + month + '.' + d.getFullYear();

    $(".form_dateStart").val(output + " 00:00:00");
```

This will be the exact solution that you are looking for

Comment: I need set current date and set time in 00:00:00

Comment: I have modified the script as per your requirement